# SMS and GPRS: Multiplexing GSM module on BeagleBone Black using n_gsm

Tags: gsm, at-command, beagleboneblack, gprs, ppp

I'm using simcom 800H cellular module with my BeagleBone Black which is very similar to the popular simcom 900. I want to do two main things with the simcom module

- Use AT commands to configure settings and send and receive messages
- Use ppp to enable internet access on the BBB through GPRS.

Now the obvious problem is that I cannot do both at the same time. I did a web search and found the following posts

1. [Using GPRS and GSM Simulatneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830279/using-gprs-and-gsm-simulatneously)
2. [Sending AT commands to SIM900 whilst pppd is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939656/sending-at-commands-to-sim900-whilst-pppd-is-active?lq=1)

The 2nd link has been particularly useful where one of the user has used the code on this [repository](https://github.com/Rtone/cmux).

The common theme has been to use the `n_gsm` module. I tried to load the module using `modprobe n_gsm` and it failed. Like the user mentioned the BBB also doesn't include the n_gsm module as default so I had to go and build a new kernel with n_gsm added as a module. However I'm having issues with including the `n_gsm` as a module. Here are the steps I followed

1. I followed [this](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/) tutorial and downloaded the right linux headers for my BBB.
2. I tried to compile the module as a Linux LKM (Loadable kernel module) as follows
3. I downloaded the n_gsm.c from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/n_gsm.c)
4. The `n_gsm.c` file had some includes which were missing in my BBB. So I downloaded them.
5. I created a makefile. My directory had `n_gsm.c` and `Makefile`

Makefile

```
obj-m += n_gsm.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This generated errors as shown in figure [image: n_gsm errors]

- I was able to successfully load a **different module** as shown in [this](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/) (the hello world of kernel modules). I also dont understand why I need to recompile the entire linux kernel to create a LKM.
- I feel I'm making some obvious errors as it looks we people were able
  to load this module successfully.
- Is this the right way to load a module and specifically `n_gsm`. **There isn't much document/tutorial on this**.
- Is there a simpler way to do this multiplexing in case all thisdoes not workout? I really like the idea of AT commands for SMS and PPP for GPRS (instead of AT commands for both).

Any tips and suggestions will be really helpful!

**Edit1** : Details about my BBB

1. kernel - Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone79
2. Distro - Debian 7.9 (wheezy)

**Edit 2** : Added details about GSM module

1. [This](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1946) is the GSM breakout board I'm using.
2. It uses [this](http://www.simcom.eu/index.php?m=termekek&prime=1&sub=40&id=0000000246) module and you can checkout the [command manual](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1946/SIM800+Series_AT+Command+Manual_V1.09.pdf) and [multiplexing application note](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1946/SIM800+Series_Multiplexer_Application+Note_V1.01.pdf).

***Update 1***

1. Thanks to @Serge, I was able to build the `n_gsm` module and add it without re-compiling the kernel. However, I still haven't been able to get the GSM module into mux mode.
2. `AT+CMUX=?`, `AT+CMUX?` and `AT+CMUX=` geneated an error on the sim800H module.
3. Here's the de-bugging I have done

   1. Played around with hardware/software and no flow. Didnt work in any mode.
   2. Set TE-TA fixed local rate `AT+IPR` to auto, 115200 and still `AT+CMUX` generates an error
   3. Tested `AT+CMUX?` on another sim900 module and that works.

Any idea why it does not work with sim800H?

Comment: what distribution you are using at your BB?

Comment: Debian wheezy. I'll edit the post shortly to add more details about the BBB.

Comment: how the module is connected: over uart or usb?

Comment: Over uart. The AT commands and PPP work individually.

Comment: I see. then I have no advice other than to resolve issues with source code you are trying to compile. sorry.

Comment: Am I compiling the n_gsm module the right way? I'm pulling the code from the official linux github page and cant imagine there would be these many errors.

Comment: the code seems to be incompatible with your kernel version. check the accompanying README

Comment: which README? How did you figure the incompatibility?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113972/discussion-between-serge-and-agm).

Answer (score 1):

The make issue in the question has been solved by downloading the n_gsm.c from [beaglebone's kernel source repository](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/tree/3.8.13-bone71-lsm303/drivers/tty) for the kernel version in use.

Comment: I was able to load the module and stuff. However, getting the gsm module to work in mux mode is an issue (see update 1). Any pointers?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no such module, so I can't reproduce the scenario, sorry.